# How to calculate differences for this data frame in R

Tags: r

I have  multiple columns, but here is a small of my data:

```html
df<- read.table(text = "Var1    M1  N1  Var2    M2  N2  Var3    M3  N3  Var4    M4  N4  Var5    M5  N5  Var6    M6  N6
 A11    1   0   A12 0.3 0.5 A21 1   0.3 A22 0.6 0   A31 1   0.2 A32 0   1
             
", header = TRUE)
```

I want to calculate differences in M and N. So, Ma-Mb and Na-Nb to get the following table

```html
Var diffM   diffN
A1  0.7 -0.5
A2  0.4  0.3
A3  1   -0.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format first and then do a group by `diff` `across`  the 'M', 'N' columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", 'grp'), 
       names_sep = "(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])") %>% 
   group_by(Var = str_sub(Var, 1, 2)) %>% 
   summarise(across(c(M, N), ~ -diff(.), .names = "diff{.col}"), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Var   diffM diffN
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A1     0.7   -0.5
#2 A2     0.4    0.3
#3 A3     1     -0.8
```

---

If we want the `sum` for 'N', use that in `summarise`

```
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", 'grp'), 
       names_sep = "(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])") %>% 
   group_by(Var = str_sub(Var, 1, 2)) %>% 
   summarise(across(c(M, N), ~ -diff(.), .names = "diff{.col}"), 
               sumN = sum(N), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Var   diffM diffN  sumN
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A1      0.7  -0.5   0.5
#2 A2      0.4   0.3   0.3
#3 A3      1    -0.8   1.2
```

Comment: If I want to sum "N", is it possible to help me? Thanks

Comment: @user330 i updated the post. Please check

Comment: `pivot_longer` seems super powerful and convenient to use, amazing! I have no idea whether `data.table::melt` can be used in a similar way

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
rbindlist(
  split.default(
    setDT(df),
    gsub("\\D", "", names(df))
  ),
  use.names=FALSE
)[
  ,
  setNames(
    lapply(.SD, function(x) diff(rev(x))),
    paste0("diff", gsub("\\d", "", names(.SD)))
  ),
  by = .(Var = gsub("\\d$", "", Var1))
]
```

gives

```
   Var diffM diffN
1:  A1   0.7  -0.5
2:  A2   0.4   0.3
3:  A3   1.0  -0.8
```